# WaitCursor doesn't show hourglass cursor

Tags: winforms

I have a form which is shown from a child form. Before a long running process I change the cursor using `Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;` However when I run the app, the cursor doesn't change to an hour glass. I even tried to do it for the mdi form. Only when I click on the form while the long running process is running do I get an hourglass and "(Not Responding)" form title.

What am I missing?

Comment: That only sets the *intention* to change the cursor.  But then you made the UI thread go completely catatonic, nothing can happen while that code is running.  Until Windows steps in to let the user know that your program is dead to the world, displaying the ghost window with "Not Responding" in the title bar.  Don't hang the UI thread, use a worker thread.  Assigning Cursor.Current instead is the sloppy quick fix.

Comment: Cursor.Current worked. You can put that as an answer.